# Get Public key from SS58 Address

Tags: substrate

According to [The Subkey Tool](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/integrate/subkey). We can generate a pub/private key using `subkey generate` like the following:

```sh
$ subkey generate
Secret phrase `cement drum say almost secret series daughter eager ceiling fetch about duck` is account:
  Secret seed:      0xb84c6858ca5f331a703203e853d3537eac0a3d4b54838dc69d8e6d395ab4ec6f
  Public key (hex): 0x5075808dbd0eb02828a525c6332596f0e95c3d0b9ecfede376195ca95bca415b
  Account ID:       0x5075808dbd0eb02828a525c6332596f0e95c3d0b9ecfede376195ca95bca415b
  SS58 Address:     5DtCbNMGwhnP5wJ25Zv59wc5aj5uo3wYdr8536qSRxbvmLdK
```

My question:

How can i get `Public key` from `SS58 Address`? In this example, Is it possible to get `0x5075808dbd0eb02828a525c6332596f0e95c3d0b9ecfede376195ca95bca415b` from `5DtCbNMGwhnP5wJ25Zv59wc5aj5uo3wYdr8536qSRxbvmLdK`?

Comment: `subkey inspect <ss58>`?

Comment: Great! Can you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `subkey inspect <ss58>`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this using polkadotjs, you can do the following

```
const { decodeAddress } = require('@polkadot/util-crypto');
const { u8aToHex } = require('@polkadot/util');
const publicKey = decodeAddress('5DSaSznmKRjt9Lvg4478V54UU8kdNyZKSQM8brSiczFR1S1H');
const hexPublicKey = u8aToHex(publicKey);
console.log(hexPublicKey);
```

Comment: Thanks - the missing manual! Why is there no proper API documentation that lists all functions? The official API doc says "This is not line-by-line documentation of all the existing function calls available". This has to be the only API I have ever used that has no documentation. I have to search all over the net for answers every day. Don't they want people to develop with it?